# Centring 3D model in SceneView not AR

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore, sceneform

I have a view that loads a 3D model with SceneView. The problem is that I have added a custom class for model rotation, but this causes the model to be displaced instead of being centered on the screen.

```kotlin
class DragRotationController(private val transformableNode: DragTransformableNode,
                             gestureRecognizer: DragGestureRecognizer
) :
    BaseTransformationController<DragGesture>(transformableNode, gestureRecognizer) {

    companion object {

        private const val initialLat = 26.15444376319647
        private const val initialLong = 18.995950736105442

        var lat: Double = initialLat
        var long: Double = initialLong
    }

    private var rotationRateDegrees = 0.5f

    public override fun canStartTransformation(gesture: DragGesture): Boolean {
        return transformableNode.isSelected
    }

    private fun getX(lat: Double, long: Double): Float {
        return (transformableNode.radius *
                cos(Math.toRadians(lat)) *
                sin(Math.toRadians(long))
                ).toFloat()
    }

    private fun getY(lat: Double): Float {
        return transformableNode.radius * sin(Math.toRadians(lat)).toFloat()
    }

    private fun getZ(lat: Double, long: Double): Float {
        return (transformableNode.radius *
                cos(Math.toRadians(lat)) *
                cos(Math.toRadians(long))
                ).toFloat()
    }

    override fun onActivated(node: Node?) {
        super.onActivated(node)
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            transformCamera(lat, long)
        }, 0)
    }

    public override fun onContinueTransformation(gesture: DragGesture) {
        val rotationAmountY = gesture.delta.y * rotationRateDegrees
        val rotationAmountX = gesture.delta.x * rotationRateDegrees
        val deltaAngleY = rotationAmountY.toDouble()
        val deltaAngleX = rotationAmountX.toDouble()

        long -= deltaAngleX
        lat += deltaAngleY

        transformCamera(lat, long)
    }

    private fun transformCamera(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        transformableNode.scene?.camera?.apply {
            localRotation = getRotation(longitude, latitude)
            localPosition = getPosition(latitude, longitude)
        }
    }

    private fun getPosition(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) = Vector3(
        getX(latitude, longitude),
        getY(latitude),
        getZ(latitude, longitude)
    )

    private fun getRotation(longitude: Double, latitude: Double): Quaternion? {
        var rotation = Quaternion.eulerAngles(Vector3(0F, 0F, 0F))
        rotation = Quaternion.multiply(
            rotation, Quaternion(
                Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f),
                (longitude).toFloat()
            )
        )
        rotation = Quaternion.multiply(
            rotation, Quaternion(
                Vector3.right(),
                (-latitude).toFloat()
            )
        )
        return rotation
    }

    public override fun onEndTransformation(gesture: DragGesture) {
        //no-op
    }
}
```

I would still like to have the rotation with this class, but I would like the model I load to appear centred and not shifted upwards as it appears in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
onActivated()
```

add these

```
transformableNode.localPosition = Vector3(0f, -0.4f, 0f)
transformCamera(lat, long-10)
```